# Struts2 checkbox with iterator

Tags: struts2

I'm Using Struts2 in jsp page i have iterator values for checkbox. how to get the values in action class? Am using javascript to validate the checkboxes. So please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe you have checkboxex something like

```
 <s:form action="myaction">
            <s:checkbox name="a" fieldValue="ORIGINATOR" value="%{value1}" label="A"/>
            <s:checkbox name="a" fieldValue="EVALUATOR" value="%{value2}" label="B"/>
            <s:checkbox name="a" fieldValue="EXECUTOR" value="%{value3}" label="C"/>
        </s:form>
```

here is how you will get values in your action class

```
public class Handler extends ActionSupport{

      private String[] a;

public void setA(String[] a){

        this.a= a;
    }

@Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {


        // use the checkbox values here

        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried your coding but unable to get the parameter value in action class

Answer (score 0):

There are two struts tags which can generate checkbox items on the page.

[checkboxlist](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/checkboxlist.html)

[checkbox](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/checkbox.html)

The tag checkboxlist is used to populate checkboxes from a map, list or array. This will generate checkboxes to the number of items in the structure you provide. The `list` attribute, which is mandatory is used to specify the list or map or array. When the form gets submitted, to get the selected items in your action object, map it using attribute `name`. i.e. to get the selected items in action, specify the `name` attribute, define an array or list with the same name in action class, provide the getter and setter for the array or list. You can refer the discussion below to know more:

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckboxlist-multiple-check-boxes-example/

The checkbox tag will generate a single checkbox item on your page. It is comparatively simple and easy to implement. Please refer the link below to understand how it works:

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/

And, to validate the checkbox items, you can implement the logic as you handle the basic html + javascript. You may use `cssClass` attribute to specify the html class while using checkboxlist and then use jQuery select by class to get the items and validate.

Comment: Verify your code has error. Assigning a to a but not to ay. public void setA(String[] ay){this.a= a;}